# How to reference organizing conference symposia / panels on CV?

Tags: conference, cv, service-activities

Presentions for papers or posters at conferences are easy to reference, but how do you reference activities such as organizing conference symposia / panels on your CV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are, of course, a number of ways to do this, as there is no fixed "CV" format even within a field, let alone across them. I will tell you my own methods for doing this:

Long sessions, such as full or half-day workshops, breakout tracks, etc. go under *Teaching Experience*, with the conference information placed in lieu of normal course information. For example:

> Session Organizer, “An Introduction to Doing Good Research”, Learning Institute, Association for Right Thinking People Annual Conference. October 2011, 2012 and 2014

Smaller sessions get pulled into *Invited Talks*, which in my CV is actually *Invited Talks and Organized Workshops*, which then have 'Panel Moderator' or 'Symposium Organizer' instead of an author. For example:

> Symposium Organizer, "Novel Methods in Being Unimpeachably Correct". 2016. Society for Doing Science Annual Meeting, Chicago, IL.

Comment: Agreed, just that I'd probably gather all such under a heading "Organization of conferences and symposia" at the end of the CV, as far as you are responsible for it in a meaningful way. If no, just leave out. It isn't very relevant for your *research* potential, anyway.

Comment: @vonbrand I'd do the same if I had a fair number of them, but if I'm running under the assumption that there are few enough of them that they would be conspicuously few in their own section. Symposium organization is, at times, a fairly strong signaling mechanism in my field, so they *do* have a relevant message for your research potential.

Answer (score 8):

I recommend including a section at the end of your CV entitled "Service", where you list things like conference/panel organization, committee memberships, refereeing activities, and the like.  Initially you may have only one or two items, but the list *will* grow over time.  As this list grows, organize it into subsections (University service vs Professional service, for example) and subsubsections (editorial boards, program committees, workshop organization, proposal reviews, refereeing, ...).

(I'm assuming that you mean the American Academic CV, which includes *everything*, and not the UK Professional CV, which is just a two-page sketch.)